# How to rotate a monitor?

Tags: monitors, monitor-stand

I have three screens connected to my PC and I want to rotate one of them so that it's vertical. I'm not talking about rotating the image; I know I can do that in Display Preferences. I am talking about physically rotating the monitor itself.

Unfortunately, none of my three screens have stands which would allow the user to pick if he wants to position the screen vertically or horizontally - only the horizontal placement is possible.

However, this is not acceptable for me and I am looking for a way to bypass this. Is there an extra piece of equipment that can be strapped on to the monitor or the stand that would allow the monitor to be vertical?

These are the screens that I have:

- Samsung S22B300
- Philips PHL 223V5
- Dell E2218HN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if any of your display has a [Vesa Mount](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_Display_Mounting_Interface). The mount itself uses 4 screws in a 75 or 100 mm square so you can use the screen in any orientation. 3rd party stands are easily available online, ranging from no-names to big brands like Dell or Iiyama. There are stands, wall mounts and desk edge mounts available. Most don't allow free rotation of the screen - you would need to unmount the screen and replace it into another orientation.

Be warned though, I've had issues with cheap mounts sagging (the last vertical angle hinge).

Also, two people are recommended for assembly.

Since you listed your monitors in comments, the Dell E2218HN does have a mount, Dell even lists it as compatible on their [MSA14 Single Monitor Arm Stand](https://www.dell.com/en-us/work/shop/dell-single-monitor-arm/apd/332-1235/monitors-monitor-accessories). That one is mounted to the back edge of your desk. While expensive, this is just an example product and there are cheaper ones. There is also a [stand](https://www.dell.com/en-us/work/shop/ergotech-dmrs-1-stand-for-lcd-display-steel-screen-size-13-inch-32-inch-desktop/apd/a9935252/monitors-monitor-accessories) but I am not 100% it will be high enough for you to mount a 22" vertically on it - it should be. The Phillips PHL 223v5 has a mount as well.

Do note that TN displays (both your Dell and Phillips) don't have good vertical angles, regardless of manufacturer boasts. I have a 22" Iiyama which had pivot in factory stand, with supposed 160 degrees vertical and it still does not look good.

Comment: Hi, I have the following screens: 

- Samsung S22B300
- Philips PHL 223v5
- Dell E2218HN

I think none of these have a Vesa Mount, but I am not sure. I have found some monitor stands online, but I am unsure about if they will be compatible with my monitors. Is there any way I can find out before buying them?

Regarding the free rotation of the screen - in any case I would like one of the three screens to be permanently vertical, so it's not an issue if the orientation is not easily changed

Comment: Please add those screens to your question.